# how to disable polymer 1.0. paper-tooltip animation

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a paper tooltip, working correctly. I'm trying to disable the fade-in / out animation, to resemble Polymer 0.5 behavior. THe animationconfig seems to be ignored. Any ideas ?

```
<paper-tooltip for="addid" position="left" animationConfig="{{tooltipAnimation}}">Tooltip text</paper-tooltip>
```

In the polymer code:

```
ready: function() {
    this.tooltipAnimation = 
      {"entry": [{"name": "fade-in-animation", "timing": {"delay": 1000}}],
       "exit": [{"name": "fade-out-animation"}]};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should write as -

```
animation-config="{{tooltipAnimation}}"
```

> Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names
>   by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the
>   dashes. For example, the attribute first-name maps to firstName.

Read [Property name to attribute name mapping](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping).